# How to handle changes to Firestore Fields when using Codable?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable

What is the best way to handle adding new attributes to an existing document in Firestore if you're using Codable?

From my understanding, Version 2 of this model would not deserialize existing data. So in this case, is it better to just make any new field optional after the first model? What is considered best practice?

Version 1

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
     @DocumentID var id: String?
     var pages: Int
}
```

Version 2

```
struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
     @DocumentID var id: String?
     var pages: Int
     var chapters: Int //Should I make this optional?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, this field needs to be of optional type otherwise your old json values won't parse.

Also init these values from a decoder in case your underlying structure gonna change.

```
public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    try super.init(from: decoder)
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
    pages = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .pages)
    chapters = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .chapters)
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use decoder even if the new field is optional? Just trying to find the best way to do it with the least amount of code. It just defeats the purpose of using Codable in the first place.

Comment: You can avoid using init method if you keep your vars as optional.